# XUnit Tests ARE Discovered, WILL Run In All Tests, but do NOT Run In Playlist

Tags: visual-studio-2017, xunit

I have a weird problem where in in VS2017 v15.6.6 my Xunit tests have been running fine all morning in both "All Tests" and a separate individual playlist.

After adding "xunit.methodDisplay" to my app.config in the test project the tests in that playlist will ONLY run in the "All Tests" list. If I try to run them in the playlist view, I get this error

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17/build/_common/
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.PerformShadowCopy(IEnumerable`1 testExtensions

My solution targets .NET Framework 4.6.1. All my versions seem to match, I have found (and verified my info matches solutions for) several questions about tests not being discovered at all or not being run in All Tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually the "Not discoverable" questions led me back to Xunit's "[Getting Started](http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-desktop)" page, which has a section all about running in VS, including this handy little gem:

[image]

Deleting this folder solved my problem.